# Permanently setting polygon/polyline segment length using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, polygon, editing, length

I'm trying to create a several hundred polygons in ArcGIS 10, each of which may have up to several hundred vertices. For consistency sake I would like each line segment in these polygons to be of a set length, say 10m.

I know you can right click and set the next segment length (or use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>) as you are drawing, but this is going to insanely repetitive if I have to do this thousands of times. Is there a way to permanently set the segment length as you are drawing a polygon or polyline?

Comment: I've not come across this requirement before but it sounds like you want to digitise lines and polygons using clicks that result in only the direction from the previous vertex being used to create the next one i.e. the distance from the previous vertex is ignored and replaced by the segment length you have set.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try splitting the lines into segments after digitizing the entire length, using the [Split command on the Editor toolbar](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/at_a_specified_distance_or_percentage/001t0000008r000000/). Alternatively, the free tool [Station Points in ET Geowizards](http://www.ian-ko.com/ET_GeoWizards/gw_NoRestrictions.htm) can be used to create points that can then be used in the [Split Line At Point](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Split_Line_At_Point/00170000003w000000/) tool.